# Using ionic2 ui components in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an existing mobile web application built with Angular 2.

Is it possible to include ionic 2 ui components in my existing app ? I dont want to change my entire app to ionic2, just the UI components.

Comment: Why you need to do this?

Comment: Well you could just add `ionic-angular` That holds most of the components

Comment: Any doc about your implementation? @gerdi

Comment: dont know of any docs but i can imagine it would be something like `npm install --save ionic-angular` and then just `import { COMPONENT } from 'ionic-angular'`

Comment: @Sampath I dont want to build the entire app in ionic. Since my app has too may components, Ionic takes too long to load especially with cordova android app. I am utilising angular 2's lazy loading to reduce initial load time. That is why i want to use ionic ui components in this app so that i can reduce ui development.

Comment: Then you can use Ionic 3 with Angular 4 no?